# How to initiate a class constructor with a class template in C++?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I wish to create an instance of `TemplateClassB` such that its private `tcA` is an instance of `TemplateClassA` with `L =1`. The program produces an error: `no matching function for call to 'TemplateClassA<>::TemplateClassA(TemplateClassA<1>)'
     : tcA(TemplateClassA<L>(2)){`

If I change the TemplateClassB to `template <typename E, typename F, int L=5>`, then there is no error. Why? How can this be fixed?

```
template <int L=5>
class TemplateClassA {
public:
  typedef unsigned TypeA;

  TemplateClassA(int i)
    : a(i+L){
  }

  int a;
};

template <typename E, typename F, int L=1>
class TemplateClassB {
public:
  typename TemplateClassA<L>::TypeA var;   

  TemplateClassB()
    : tcA(TemplateClassA<L>(2)){
  }

  TemplateClassA<> tcA;
}; 

int main(){
  TemplateClassA<> A(1);
  TemplateClassB<int, int> B;

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to build a factory? Your code is (just a tad bit) confusing.

Comment: where you are using typename E and typename F in your class TemplateClassB.If you are not using these types, possibly you should remove it and just use int L = 1 in the this case as well which you have done for TemplateClassA.

Comment: I think I found the problem. If I replace `TemplateClassA<> tcA;` with `TemplateClassA<L> tcA;`, then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcA` is `TemplateClassA<5> and you are trying to assign`TemplateClassA(2)` to it, they are distinct types.

```
template <typename E, typename F, int L=1>
class TemplateClassB {
public:
  typename TemplateClassA<L>::TypeA var;   

  TemplateClassB()
    : tcA(TemplateClassA<L>(2)){  // here L is 2
  }

  TemplateClassA<> tcA;  // by default L=5
};
```

you need to write type conversion function or make `tcA` same type as `TemplateClassA<1>`
which is:

```
TemplateClassA<L> tcA;  // L is 1 now
//            ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the line:

```
TemplateClassA<> tcA;
```

Change it to:

```
TemplateClassA<1> tcA;
```

Answer (score 1):

TemplaceClassB::tcA is of type TemplateClassA<5>

With your initial declaration, you are trying to initialize it as if it were TemplateClassA<1>